# How to set interactive PDF form in read-only mode while writing as new PDF by using Apache PDFBox?

Tags: pdfbox

I am using **Apache PDFBox library** to fill information in fillable PDF form(AcroFrom). After complete information filling, I needs to write as a new PDF file *(in non-editable format)*.

I tried setReadOnly() method, which is available in AccessPermission class. But still I can able to edit the values in new created PDF document.

**Code:**

```
private static PDDocument _pdfDocument;

public static void main(String[] args) {

String originalPdf = "C:/sample/Original.pdf";
String targetPdf = "C:/sample/target.pdf";

 try {
        populateAndCopy(originalPdf, targetPdf);
 -----------
 -----------
 -----------
 -----------
 }

 } // Main method complted




private static void populateAndCopy(String originalPdf, String targetPdf) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
    _pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(originalPdf);

    _pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();

    _pdfDocument.getCurrentAccessPermission().setCanModify(false);
    _pdfDocument.getCurrentAccessPermission().setReadOnly();
    System.out.println(_pdfDocument.getCurrentAccessPermission().isReadOnly());
    _pdfDocument.save(targetPdf);
    _pdfDocument.close();
}
```

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: What exactly is your aim? Do you want to make the AcroForm fields read-only (by setting the **Ff** form field flag *ReadOnly*)? That's what the title of your question sounds like. Or do you want to use access permissions to signal restrictions on changing the document in general? That's where your code is headed.

Comment: I want to make it all form fields (like Text, Check, Combo, list, Radio and Button) as read only. Save it as flat format PDF file with data and without any interactive functionality. Thanks advance...

Comment: *Save it as flat format PDF file* - this sounds like you want to flatten the form - *with data* - this sounds like not flattening. So... Do you want to *flatten* it, i.e. merge the form field appearances in the normal page content and then drop the form fields entirely? Or do you want to have the data available easily which would mean not flattening but merely setting the field ReadOnly?

Comment: Yes Correct. I want to merge data with blank PDF form and settin the form field read-only.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {

    try {
    String formTemplate = "xyz.pdf";

    // load the document
    PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(formTemplate));

    // get the document catalog
    PDAcroForm acroForm = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

    // as there might not be an AcroForm entry a null check is necessary
    if (acroForm != null)
    {
        // Retrieve an individual field and set its value.
        PDTextField field1 = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField( "_lastName" );
        field1.setValue("pppp");
        PDTextField field2 = (PDTextField) acroForm.getField( "_firstName" );
        field2.setValue(aaaa");
    }


    // flatten() method saves the PDF read only
    acroForm.flatten();

    // Save and close the filled out form.
    pdfDocument.save("xyz.pdf");
    pdfDocument.close();
    System.out.println("Done!!");

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

Comment: That is flattening. He doesn't want that, see the last two comments.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not set any encryption, that is the problem.

Try this:

```
    AccessPermission ap = new AccessPermission();
    ap.setCanModify(false);
    ap.setReadOnly();
    StandardProtectionPolicy spp = new StandardProtectionPolicy("owner-password", "", ap);
    spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(128);
    doc.protect(spp);
    doc.save(targetPdf);
    doc.close();
```

I've set 128 as the keylength as 256 is not supported in 1.8 and 40 is too short.

A user will be able to open the document without password (see the empty password parameter), but he'll have only the restricted rights.

Comment: I tried this code. But still I can able to edit the value in PDF. Thanks advance...

Comment: Please try again with a snapshot of the upcoming version 1.8.8
https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox/1.8.8-SNAPSHOT/

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all fields in the acroform and set them to readonly:

```java
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDAcroForm acroForm = catalog.getAcroForm();
List<PDField> fieldList = acroForm.getFields();
for (PDField field : fieldList) {
    field.setReadOnly(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
        AccessPermission ap = new AccessPermission();
        ap.setCanPrint(false);
        ap.setCanModify(false);
        ap.setCanFillInForm(false);
        ap.setCanModifyAnnotations(false);
        ap.setCanPrintDegraded(false);
        ap.setReadOnly();
        ap.setCanExtractContent(false);
        ap.setCanExtractForAccessibility(false);
        doc.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);

        /**
         *  To encrypt PDF with password.
         * @ownerpassword - used to control access permissions for the document, such as printing, modifying, copying text, etc.
         * @userPassword - document open password
         * Here encrypting pdf with Last Four Digits of User Account Number, User can only View PDF,can't do any other actions.
         * In order to print/modify some special access is required that owner password.
         */
        String selectedAccNumber = maskedAccountNumberMap.get("maskedAccNumber");
        String userPassword = "";
        if(selectedAccNumber != null && selectedAccNumber.length() >= 4) {
            userPassword = selectedAccNumber.substring(selectedAccNumber.length() - 4);
        }
        StandardProtectionPolicy policy = new StandardProtectionPolicy("ownerpassword",userPassword,ap);
        doc.protect(policy);
```